# Answer to question appears to help but isn't up to personal standards, delete it?

Tags: discussion

I just answered a question and I didn't think the answer was up to my personal standard so I decided to delete it. However it appeared that it might have helped the questioner out as they posted verbatim a code snippet that was identical to the suggestion in my answer. What is the general consensus for deleting answers in a situation like this?

For reference here's the question ["unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'' message in visual studio running python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834968/unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-str-message-in-visual-studio-ru)

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You're asking if your answer should remain deleted?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, essentially yes. I'm just wondering what the community consensus is when it comes to deleting answers that might have been useful to other people but aren't up to personal standards.

Comment: Charles Duffy's answer seems to suffice.